# Show the_content() from specific category

Tags: wordpress

I need to find out how to list my content data on a page/ section when I click on a specific category link.

After a few hours I realise that help from stackoverflow is what i need!

The function remind a little of: http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/wordpress-category-post-list-493.html

I need to list my data (title, the_content etc) from the specific category and not all categories with the titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While that post gives you a good start, here is the code that I would use

```
// Set the desired category
$category = 1;

// Make query for posts in the category
$my_query = new WP_Query();
$my_query->query(
    array(
        'cat' => $category,
        // Does not show sticky posts; use 'caller_get_posts' if using < WP 3.1
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1 
    )
);

// Make sure some posts were found.
if($my_query->have_posts()) 
{
    // Loop through each post found.
    while($my_query->have_posts())
    {
        // Setup the post data to use
        $my_query->the_post();
        global $post;

        // Echo out the title; Note that no formatting has been done
        the_title();
     the_content();                     
    }
}
```

Now, you can also get the title with either:

```
$title = get_the_title($post->ID);
$title = $post->post_title;
```

Additionally, you can get the post content with:

```
$content = $post->post_content;
```

Also, you can get the category using any of these parameters:

```
cat (int) - use category id.
category_name (string) - use category slug (NOT name).
category__and (array) - use category id.
category__in (array) - use category id.
category__not_in (array) - use category id.
```

More about the WP_Query class can be found here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: What to write in the $category var? :-s I need itself to find it dynamically :-/

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. In what context would you use this code? The category ids can most likely be found, I just need to know when you might execute the code to help you figure out how to find the category ids.

Comment: I use the category.php in the my theme to show up the data. 
Category.php code with your code. http://pastie.textmate.org/private/gd0umxohmpixugaf3mbpdw 

And the link comes from the sidebar.php and looks like: 
http://pastie.textmate.org/private/qvdwvoe5leb6j1hveimhxw

Comment: You can get the category id with `get_query_var('cat');` or the whole category object with `$cat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'),false);`.